# How to show reflection of textures in libgdx?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, libgdx

I need to create an OpenGL ES app (preferably using libGDX) that shows a spinning texture that has a reflection of some sort beneath it.

I've searched the web, and found some very old tutorials of how to do it in OpenGL.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to do it on libGdx or on Android, and if I'm forced to use OpenGL 2 instead of 1.x.

Is there any tutorial of achieving reflection of a texture in Java, Android or libgdx?

---

I've made some small progress, but I still need more help.

Currently the code of showing the texture is based on [this link](http://obviam.net/index.php/texture-mapping-opengl-android-displaying-images-using-opengl-and-squares/), and I've modified it so that it would show the spinning image and its reflection.

However, I have some bad issues with it:

1. it's almost like a perfect mirror. I need to put some kind of special effect so that it has some kind of gradient effect on it.
2. the images might go over one another, and they are not transparent. If I move the reflection a bit closer to the spinning image, I could see that they overlap each other.

The code is here:

```
public class GlRenderer implements Renderer

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 gl)
  {
  gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  square.draw(gl);
  // draw normal spinning image
  gl.glLoadIdentity();
  gl.glColor4f(1f,1f,1f,1f);
  gl.glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);
  gl.glRotatef(rotationAngle++,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
  square.draw(gl);
  // draw reflection
  gl.glLoadIdentity();
  gl.glColor4f(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,1.0f);
  gl.glTranslatef(0.0f,-1.0f,-3.0f);
  gl.glRotatef(-80+180,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  gl.glRotatef(rotationAngle,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
  }
```

Is there anyone that could help me on this?

Comment: what's your purpose of "reflection"? you mean flipping horizontal or vertical?

Comment: the purpose is to make it more realistic . the reflection is beneath the item , for example : http://library.creativecow.net/articles/okerstrom_jon/reflections/OddReflection1.jpg

Comment: You can flip the texture vertical and give it some transparency (alpha) by calling spriteBatch.setColor(1,1,1,alpha).
but this method gives a constant transparency and I don't know how to make a fade out effect.

Comment: since i'm a little bit noob in this matter , i would really appreciate a code example that shows how to do it . also , i think a gradient effect would be better .

Answer (score 1):

For a perfect effect you will need to do 2 things.
Assuming you used Image class to render it,
first, is to put the same image bellowthe original one and use the scaleY to flip it vertically.

this will create reflection effect, but you will need to apply same things that you applied to first image to the second one, like movement, rotation, whatever you did to it.

Besides that you will probably need your reflection image to fade out like a gradient, if you are doing everything on a solid not moving background, you can create a third image which is a gradient png from transparent to the color of your background, and put it over the reflection image. If you have a dynamic background, then you will probably need to use shaders (sorry, openGL 2 only). You can read more on how to write custom shaders here: http://blog.josack.com/2011/08/my-first-2d-pixel-shaders-part-3.html (A great tutorial)]

Hope that helps. There might be other solution I don't know about, so keep researching, but this is what came to my mind.

Comment: this trick is already shown on many places , but i've asked for an alternative , do you really mean that always, when there is a reflection , it's basically re-drawing the same objects again yet mirrored ? isn't there an easier way to do it ? also , can you please give a sample (shortest ) code of how to do it with gradient effect ?

Comment: I am not sure there is an alternative though I might be wrong. There is plenty of things you can do with Shaders. If you whant the example of making a gradient, one way of doing it is for example: gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords)*vec4((v_texCoords.y+4)/3.0, (v_texCoords.y+4)/3.0, (v_texCoords.y+4)/3.0, 1.0); inside the fragment shader, that should be applied to mirrored actor, but using shaders is not that simple if you are not familir you should do some big research, it is not possible to explain with simple piece of code.